# Where can I compare remote assistance software?

Tags: untagged

I'm looking for a place where I can compare remote assistance software.  I'm hoping to see what's good for businesses and individuals.

Answer (score 10):

If you are looking for a place to compare remote assistance software, I recommend Thailand, for the following reasons:

1. Thailand is likely to be genuinely remote, relative to the physical location of your end users.  This will help to ensure a realistic test.
2. Because it is a popular destination for international tourists, decent internet access and GSM phone service are widely available for a reasonable fee throughout Thailand.
3. Thailand is full of beautiful places (and people) that will constantly make you smile.
4. Prices are generally about one-tenth what we expect to pay in the West.
5. You will have access to an unlimited supply of truly delicious Thai food.

Upon arriving in Thailand to conduct your test, I would suggest referring to the following web resource (courtesy Wikipedia) for an unbiased list of remote support software packages:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software

<s>By the way, if you are looking for a remote support solution that is easy to use, fully functional, and free for *both* business and personal use, [Mikogo](http://www.mikogo.com) comes recommended.</s> (As of October 2011, Mikogo now requires a fee for business use.)

Comment: Best literal answer I've seen in a long time.

Comment: It wouldn't be too remote if you are actually in Thailand and the OP has given no indication of his/her users' location(s).

Comment: Fortunately, Thailand is home to only 66.4 million people (about 1% of the world's population) and only 17.4 million internet users (again, about 1% of the global count). Therefore, for any given end user in the world, there is a 99% probability that Thailand is a remote location.

Comment: So does this mean you're getting [Altruist] *and* [Investor] for this?  :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good comparison of Remote Access Applications on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software)

You might also check out this [Site](http://www.webconferencing-test.com/en/webconference_home.html) which is focussed on Webconferencing (not exactly what you were looking for but in my experience many vendors for Remote Assistance have got products in the Webconferencing market).

If you would like a suggestion: [Netviewer](http://netviewer.com). 
It has a good amount of acceptance because it complies with high security standards.

I am not affiliated with that company, we just use their application to troubleshoot support requests on customer sites. In fact it is one of the few tools our customers (Banks) are allowed to use.